# prompt list of files before execution of rm

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rm

I started using "sudo rm -r" to delete files/directories. I even put it as an alias of rm.

I normally know what I am doing and I am quite experience linux user.

However, I would like that when I press the "ENTER", before the execution of rm, a list of files will show up on the screen and a prompt at the end to OK the deletion of files.

Options -i -I -v does not do what I want. I want only one prompt for all the printed files on screen.

Thank you.

Comment: My personal opinion is that a "quite experienced Linux user" would not even consider aliasing `rm` to `sudo rm -r`... That's just a BOOOM!!! waiting for a critical time to happen...

Comment: @twalberg a quite experienced Linux user has had time to consider a lot of bad ideas. How else do you get experienced?

Comment: @Kojiro Not saying a quite experienced user would never have considered that in the past, but rather that by the time you've considered a fair number of bad ideas and rejected them and become quite experienced, you would then not go back to certain bad ideas and adopt them anyway... (and, it was, after all, explicitly stated that that was just *my* opinion...)

Comment: @Kojiro @twalberg We've all had plenty of time to *consider* bad ideas. I know I've even implemented plenty. But to `alias rm="sudo rm -r"` is downright reckless…also in my own opinion, of course. Even if you were to use it instead of `rm` moving forward, `alias rmr!="sudo rm -r"` would be so much better. Flying in the face of convention should always give you pause. If your workflow is that much more efficient by elevating every use of `rm`, I would recommend looking at your user, group, and permission management long before pulling out the C4 for every little demo job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
##
# Double-check files to delete.
delcheck() {
  printf 'Here are the %d files you said you wanted to delete:\n' "$#"
  printf '"%s"\n' "$@"
  read -p 'Do you want to delete them? [y/N] ' doit
  case "$doit" in
    [yY]) rm "$@";;
    *) printf 'No files deleted\n';;
  esac
}
```

This is a shell function that (when used properly) will do what you want. However, if you *load* the function in your current shell then try to use it with `sudo`, it won't do what you expect because `sudo` creates a separate shell. So you'd need to make this a shell script…

```
#!/bin/bash

… same code as above …

# All this script does is create the function and then execute it.
# It's lazy, but functions are nice.
delcheck "$@"
```

…then make sure `sudo` can access it. Put it in some place that is in the `sudo` execution PATH (Depending on `sudo` configuration.) Then if you *really* want to execute it precisely as `sudo rm -r *` you will still need to name the script `rm`, (which in my opinion is dangerous) and make sure its PATH is *before* `/bin` in your PATH. (Also dangerous). But there you go.

Comment: Thank you @kojiro, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice option

Alias `rm` to `echo | xargs -p rm`

The `-p` option means "interactive" - it will display the entire command (including any expanded file lists) and ask you to confirm

It will NOT ask about the recursively removed files. But it will expand `rm * .o` to:

```
rm -rf * .o
rm -rf program.cc program.cc~ program program.o backup?... # NO NO NO NO NO!
```

Which is much nicer than receiving the error

```
rm: .o file not found
```

**Edit:** corrected the solution based on chepner comment. My previous solutions had a bug :(

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `echo`. Just using `xargs -p rm -rf $*` would work

Comment: Since aliases don't take arguments, `$*` would refer to the current shell's arguments, not the files used with the the `rm` alias.

Comment: @chepner - ehm, you're right. But my second suggestion still works as the arguments are at the end of the alias

Answer (score 1):

This simple script prompts for a y response before deleting the files specified.

rmc script file:

```
read -p "ok to delete? " ans
case $ans in
    [yY]*) sudo rm "$@" ;;
    *) echo "Nothing deleted";;
esac
```

Invoke thus

```
./rmc *.tmp
```

Comment: `$*` is not what you want. If one of the arguments is "-rf /" you'll be asked a scary question. Use `"$@"` including the quotes.

Comment: I tried your script, but still doesn't list the files when I use `sudo rm -r *` to delete all the files in the current directory.

Comment: @user112693 The script will do the deletion. If all files in the current directory are to be deleted, try `./rmc *`

Answer (score 0):

I created a script to do this. The solution is similar to @kojiro's.

Save the script with the filename `del`. Run the command `sudo chmod a=r+w+x del` to make the script an executable. In the directory in which you want to save the script, export the path by entering `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/del/executable` in your '~/.bashrc' file and run `source ~/.bashrc`.

Here, the syntax of `rm` is preserved, except instead of typing `rm ...`, type `del ...` where `del` is the name of the bash script below.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Safely delete files

args=("$@") # store all arguments passed to shell
N=$#        # number of arguments passed to shell

#echo $@ 
#echo $#
#echo ${args[@]:0}

echo "Files to delete:"
echo

n=`expr $N - 1`
for i in `seq 0 $n`
do
    str=${args[i]}
    if [ ${str:0:1} != "-" ]; then
        echo $str
    fi
done
echo 

read -r -p "Delete these files? [y/n] " response
case $response in
    [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])

    rm ${args[@]:0}
esac
```